# Endly error related to ssh

Tags: docker, end-to-end, endly

I using endly for end to end testing and my application is running on docker container, and I am facing this error. I already have my secret keys/folder in place.

`[run[build]run|build[Init]docker.run ssh: no key found at exec.extract                                           error]
[run[build]run|build[Init]docker.run build_Init: ssh: no key found at docker.run/exec.extract at workflow.run    error]
[run[build]run|build[Init]docker.run build: build_Init: ssh: no key found at docker.run/exec.extract at workflow error]
build: build_Init: ssh: no key found at docker.run/exec.extract at workflow.run at workflow.run
[run[build]run|build[Init]docker.run run_init: build: build_Init: ssh: no key found at docker.run/exec.extract a error]`

I followed the steps mentioned in github.com/viant/endly/tree/master/doc/secrets link. The contents of my localhost.json is {"Username":"xxx","EncryptedPassword":"xxx","PrivateKeyPath":"xxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}

Comment: Please provide more information, we cannot see if your Dockerfile/compose file is properly configured and we don't really know if the files are in the proper location inside container.

Answer (score 0):

You would get this error message in endly if there is an error during ssh if endly is unable to use the secrets/credentials provided to ssh.

Could you provide additional details on the credentials file.
1. How you went about creating the file.
2. Contents of the file without your password.

I am assuming your are configuring to ssh to local when building and deploying you app so the secret file would be localhost.json.

Please refer to [endly secret](https://github.com/viant/endly/tree/master/doc/secrets) for creating credentials.

Comment: Updated the question with details

Comment: For some reason you seem to have provided ".pub" in your private key path. You should remove that part of it from the credentials and it would work.